# Overflow-y doesn't work with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

According to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698151/ng-repeat-overflows-vertically), div needs to be set to a fixed height, but it doesn't work here with this following code.

```
<div style="margin-top:0.5vh;">
      <div style="height:200px;border:1px solid red;overflow:auto;" ng-init = "home_init()">
        <ol>
        <li ng-repeat= "site in sites">
          <button ng-if="!(site.Initial===flash_site)" class="button button-block" style="background-color:#{{site.Color}};" ng-click="site_selected({{site}})">
            <b>{{site.Name}}</b>
          </button>
          <button ng-if="(site.Initial===flash_site)" class="button button-block" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
            <b>{{site.Name}}</b>
          </button>
        </li>
      </ol>
   </div>
</div>
```

Tried to do this,

```
<div style="height:200px;overflow-y:auto;">
  <div style="min-height:200px">
    <div ng-repeat="site in sites">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and a few other ways, really don't understand why it the div doesn't contain the ng-repeat elements.

Please if anyone can explain why?

**Image**

This is where scroll should be, on the red border. "Queentown" is hidden below the parent div, underneath the red border. [image: Hello NZ]

**UPDATE**

Actually any of the answers below were correct, while it couldn't be used in my code was this culprit . A scroll class was enable, and by , it turned off the scroll and now any of the answers cause be use.

By the way, thank you for your time and effect. Appreciate it.

Comment: Not clear what problem is here. Create a demo so we can see your issue

Comment: sorry, I tried to make jsfiddler, but was unsuccessful. My intension is having a fixed size parent div, when the child div gets bigger than the parent div and then scroll is enable for user. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: hard to help when we can't reproduce a problem. Nothing irregular shown in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QiRBJC1i9MGSoKz6EUQC?p=preview)

```
<button ng-if="!(site.Initial===flash_site)" class="button button-block" ng-style="{'background-color': site.Color}" ng-click="site_selected(site)">
```

`ng-click="site_selected({{site}})` -- you don't need `{{}}` here.

`style="background-color:#{{site.Color}};"` -- you don't need `{{}}` here as well.

change `style` to `ng-style`to dynamically render color.

If you want to user color codes then concat `#` with `color`

```
ng-style="{'background-color': '#'+site.Color}"
```

Comment: Thanks, Ravi. Normally I don't use {} with style or ng-click, but in this case, somehow it doesn't work when {} is not included. It is strange, but it works. Problem here is, getting ng-repeat to render inside div which shows scroll when the inner div passes its parent height. Does this make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this below code:

```html
<div style="height:200px;overflow-y:auto;" ng-init="init()">
  <div style="min-height:200px">  
      <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

try this link 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NagarajanM/r5j3mbn3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="height:200px;overflow-y:auto;" ng-init="init()">
  <div style="min-height:200px">  
      <ul>
    <!--<li ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</li>-->
           <li>x</li>
           <li>x</li>
            <li>x</li>
            <li>x</li>
             <li>x</li>
              <li>x</li>
                <li>x</li>
                  <li>x</li>
                   <li>x</li>
           <li>x</li>
            <li>x</li>
            <li>x</li>
             <li>x</li>
              <li>x</li>
                <li>x</li>
                  <li>x</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I Given An Example with Static Li Try It Once

Comment: Sorry, I tried the above code but it didn't work. I notice, regardless how small or big I made to the inner div. It doesn't affect the list, and the list is still going out the parent div. Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: Try also adding max-height to outer div. and, try using flex box as the outer div container's style (if you're not already)